# Octokit Ruby gem to get list of npm packages from private registry

Tags: ruby, octokit

I'd like to use Octokit Ruby gem to get a list of npm packages from a private GitHub package registry.

I've successfully gotten the results using [this cURL command](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/packages/packages?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-packages-for-an-organization)

```
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  "https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/packages?package_type=npm"
```

I'm not seeing an analogous strategy in [Octokit Ruby gem docs](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb).

Any ideas?

Comment: After further exploration, I don't think the Octokit gem supports such a request.  I ended up just re-writing the cURL in Ruby using `uri` and `net/http`.